# Simple if else statement won't work

Tags: php

I have a page.html with just 48 in it. I can't get this if statement to work.

```
<?php 
  $myFile = 'http://site.com/page.html';
  $content = file_get_contents($myFile);
?>
<?php $num = "48"; ?>
<?php if ($content == $num): ?>
    true
<?php else: ?>
    false
<?php endif;  ?>
```

If I do this it works.

```
<?php if ($content == 48): ?>
    true
<?php else: ?>
    false
<?php endif;  ?>
```

How can I change this to make it work?

Comment: Try to cast $num to an integer, $num = "48" is a string.

Comment: have you confirmed `$content` holds a value of `48`. COnfirm using an `echo`

Comment: Is there a newline character after the `48` in the file?  Also, don't forget that PHP has one of the dumbest operators of any programming language:  [`===`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: 48 == "48" would be true so that's not a problem

Comment: 1. `echo $content` returns 48 2. There is only one line in the file. Not sure what a "newline character" is. 3. This is just a little test I'm doing. The real $num will be an id from a table which returns a regular 48.

Comment: Nasty Setup You got there... Why don't you use {BRACKETS}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this should work:

```
<?php 
  $myFile = 'http://site.com/page.html';
  $content = file_get_contents($myFile);
?>
<?php $num = "48"; ?>
<?php if (trim($content) == $num): ?>
    true
<?php else: ?>
    false
<?php endif;  ?>
```

..by using [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) which removes these characters:

- " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
- "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the value of `$content` contains `"48\n"`, i.e. the number 48 followed by a new line (or something similar). This is equal (with non-strict comparison) to the int `48`, but not to the string `"48"`.

The way to work around it is to cast `$content` to an int before making the comparison:

```
$content = (int) file_get_contents($myFile);
```

Comment: beat me to it, I think the confusion is the comparison between a string and integer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're evaluating a string in the first snippet an integer in the second. Make sure you casting it to an integer if that's they data type you're after.

```
$content = (int) file_get_contents($myFile);
```